# App_GlobalResources Compilation Error on Apache

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono

I wrote an ASP.NET application and am running it on apache with mod mono. I get this error when trying to run it. It runs fine in Visual Studio and Mono Develop

```
Compilation Error

Description: Error compiling a resource required to service this request. Review your source file and modify it to fix this error.

Compiler Error Message:
App_GlobalResources.383ec40d.resources.dll
```

I have resx files in App_GlobalResources. Not sure why I am getting this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what caused the original problem but I did get around it by precompilling my webapp using:

```
aspnet_compiler -p physicalOrRelativePath -v / targetPath
```